# Copy an .app file in os x

Tags: java, macos

I'm trying to move an app file in OS X using the FileInputStream's transferTo method, but keep getting FileNotFoundException (No such file or directory). I know this isn't the case because the .exists() method returns true when I run it on the app file. I thought it had to do with File permissions but after a few tests that doesn't seem to be the case. Here is the code I'm using to move the file:

```
public static void moveFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;

    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();

        long count = 0;
        long size = source.size();
        source.transferTo(count, size, destination);
    }
    finally {
        if(source!=null) {
            source.close();
        }

        if(destination!=null) {
            destination.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:** The title has been changed from "Move an .app file in os x" to "Copy an .app file in os x". I need to keep the original file intact.

**EDIT 2:** I was able to copy the file by means of the [Apache Commons FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) as suggested by Joel Westberg (specifically the copyDirectory method). The problem I'm facing now is when I go to run the copied app bundle the app bounces in the dock perpetually and never runs. Any ideas on why this is?

**EDIT 3:** I have figured out how to fix the perpetually bouncing problem. It turns out when I copied the app bundle that it didn't set 2 unix scripts to executable that needed to be. I simply used the setExecutable method in the File class to fix this.

Comment: Not sure what would cause that. Can you verify that a regular copy via your Terminal works as expected? `cp -r YourApp.app /path/to/somewhere/YourApp.app`

Comment: I figured out why this was happening and was able to fix it. There are two unix scripts in the app bundle that were not set to be executable when copied with the copyDirectory() method. I was used the setExecutable() method in the File class to fix this, and now everything works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is that there is no such thing as a `.app` file in OSX terminology. The .app that you see is a folder. You'll get FileNotFound when trying to read it as a file, because it isn't a file.

If you're on Java 7 you can use the new [Files.move()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) method to perform the action you want regardless of it being a File or Folder.

**EDIT**: As *MadProgrammer* suggested in the comments, it would be even easier to simply use [File.renameTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) which has been around much longer.

Comment: You could also try [`File#renameTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29)

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. 

I am on Java 7, but I'd like to make this application as portable as possible without distributing a specific version of the JRE with it.

I'll give _MadProgrammer_'s suggestion a go. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: Have a read of the docs, the functionality of `renameTo` is platform dependent and may not move files across drives or networks.  Should be fine for same drive moves though

Comment: Yeah. If you want to be sure on Java 6, you can give [Apache Commons FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) a try, which will handle both cases.

Comment: I'm reading over the docs right now. I'm not sure what I was thinking (the name of the method should have given it away) but this function actually isn't what I need. 

The fault is mine, the title should have read "Copy an .app file in os x" not move. I need to keep a copy of an .app file (specifically Minecraft.app) so I can launch it through my program.

I'll edit the question to reflect this.